# C# DynamicJsonを使用してWeatherHacksから天気予報を取得すると必ず最低気温がNullになるのは？

Tags: c#, json, api

お世話になります。

C#(.Net4.6.1)でLivedoorのWeatherHacksからDynamicJsonで天気予報を取得する
コードを書いています。
http://sh-yoshida.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/08/09/121545
こちらのサイト様のサンプルをそのまま流用し、実際に成功はしているのですが、
何故か最低気温だけが常にNull(表記上は"---")になってしまうのですが、これは
何が原因なのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

該当のAPIを叩くと「当日/翌日/明後日」のデータが返ってくるかと思いますが、呼び出したタイミングによって気温データが`null`になることがあるようです。
14時時点で試してみると翌日分のデータには最低気温の値も含まれていました。実行する時間帯を変えて試してみるとよいかもしれません。

参考：
[jqを使って今日の天気を取得 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/takaya1992/items/94b86d6b8237a638fa16)

> 最高気温と最低気温が"不明"と表示されていますが、どうも天気予報の取得に利用しているAPI（Weather Hacks）の仕様らしく、時間帯によっては気温の部分がnullで返ってくるぽいです。

Comment: 早速の回答、ありがとうございます。結局のところ、Nullになって帰ってきても失敗やエラーではなく、データがないのでNullが正しく帰ってきている…ということでしょぅか。ありがとうございました。もっと良く見てみることにします。